# How to convert Any hashable data to send as parameters for making an API call using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a function which I call when the user is clicking on LOG IN inside the app. I get the user entered password and username in the Anyhashable format. Alamofire call is made where the userDataContent is passed as the parameter.
My login function,

```
    func loginWithUserData(userData: Dictionary<String, Any> 
          ,completion: @escaping (_ success:DataResponse<Any>)->Void) {
           print("userDataContent in loginWithUsertDataCall: ", userData) 
NetworkManager.sharedNetworkManager.performNetworkOperation(url: myEndpoint().userSession(), httpmethod: .post, parameters: userData) { response in
        completion(response)
    }
}
```

I'm getting the below as my userData(Which contains username and password),

```
    userDataContent in loginWithUsertDataCall:  
    ["user": 
        [AnyHashable("password"): <TextFieldValidator: 0x7fa94e89aa00; 
            baseClass = UITextField; 
            frame = (0 0; 155.333 23.3333);
            text = '**MYPASSWORD123**'; 
            opaque = NO;
            autoresize = RM+BM; 
            gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000a468a0>; 
            layer = <CALayer: 0x604000833be0>>, 
        AnyHashable("email"): <TextFieldValidator: 0x7fa94e90be00; 
            baseClass = UITextField; 
            frame = (0 0; 263.667 23.3333); 
            text = '**myloginEmail@test.com'**; 
            opaque = NO; 
            autoresize = RM+BM; 
            gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x604000a547f0>; 
            layer = <CALayer: 0x604000638840>>
        ]
    ]
```

My question is, how should the Anyhashable be modified so that I can send the username and password as parameters in the Alamofire Network call I'm making. Any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: Why do you send `TextFieldValidator` which seems to be a subclass of `UITextField`? Why don't you just sent its `text` property? It should be ["user:["password":\(textField1.text), "email":\(textField2.text)]] where `textField1` & `textField2` correspond to the correct `TextFieldValidator`.

Comment: @SeaWarrior404 check answer hope this will work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you have a `UITextField` subclass named `TextFieldValidator`.

You do:

```
let userData = ["user": ["password": myTextFieldValidatorForPassword,
                         "email": myTextFieldValidatorForEmail]]
```

Instead you should do:

```
let userData = ["user": ["password": myTextFieldValidatorForPassword.text,
                         "email": myTextFieldValidatorForEmail.text]]
```

Because you are interested in the `text` value of theses textfields, not in the UI object. You can use whatever UI object, your API doesn't care about that, it cares about the String value.

Answer (score 0):

create a string of parameter and convert like as below

[image]

```
     let ParameterString = "{\"auth\":{\"email\":\"\(ws_email)\",\"password\":\"\(ws_password)\"},\"emailId\":\"\(EmailId)\"}"

    let parameters = self.convertToDictionary(text: ParameterString)
    static func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {

        if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: Why use a String? Why not creating directly a Dictionary?